# Combining regplot with piecewise linear regression on a Facetgrid with seaborn

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I want to plot on a grid my data with associated errorbars and a piecewise linear regression through the mean of each timepoint. I have my data in a pandas dataframe and would like to us seaborn to do the job.

If I use seaborns factorplot I get close.

```
g = sns.factorplot(x="Time", y='value', hue="Name",
                col="PEAK", data=meltdf,
                size=4, aspect=1.0,col_wrap=3,sharey=False,scale=0.7)
```

[output for the factorplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NPcGh.png)

But notice that my xaxis is not scaled correctly(this makes sense since the factorplot is designed for categorical comparisons)

If I instead create a FacetGrid and map regplot and plt.plot onto the grid I get correct spacing on the xaxis and keep error bars etc. but the linear regression is not how I want it

```
meltdf = pd.melt(Conc_norm.drop(['GLC','pan','Ratio %'],axis=1),
id_vars=['Name','Time'], var_name='PEAK')

g = sns.FacetGrid(meltdf, col="PEAK",hue='Name', col_wrap=4,sharey=False)
g.map(sns.regplot, "Time", "value",fit_reg=False, x_estimator=np.mean);
g.map(plt.plot, "Time", "value");
```

[output for the Facetgrid mapped with regplot and plt.plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sgndy.png)

Now comes the question:
How do I plot a piecewise linear regression between the points in the plot?

Thanks,

Comment: I think your second approach should work if you sort the dataframe on `Time` before plotting.

Comment: Sorting on time will improve the appearance but it will stil plot a line through all Time,value coordinates. What I want is to plot something ala. df.groupby('Time').mean() but I cannot figure how to do that

Comment: Ah, yeah, you'll need to write a little plotting function then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After trawling the net and reading many of mwaskom's excellent answers it seems I have found a working solution

```
def _plotmean(x, *args, **kwargs):
    ax = plt.gca()
    data = kwargs.pop('data')
    data = data.groupby(x).mean()
    data.plot(ax=ax, **kwargs)

Conc_norm.sort_values('Time', inplace=True)

meltdf = pd.melt(Conc_norm.drop(['GLC','pan','Ratio %'], axis=1),
                 id_vars=['Name','Time'], var_name='PEAK')

g = sns.FacetGrid(meltdf, col="PEAK", hue='Name', col_wrap=3,sharey=False)
g.map(sns.regplot, "Time", "value", fit_reg=False, x_estimator=np.mean)
g.map_dataframe(_plotmean, "Time")
g.add_legend()
```

[working output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0GnNs.png)